# Change time interval of scheduler at run time

Tags: swift, cocoa, scheduler, macos-sierra

Here is the code:

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        lbl.drawsBackground = true
        lbl.backgroundColor = NSColor.black
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0/Double(hz * 2), repeats: true, block: toggleBackground)
    }

    var hz = 40

    func toggleBackground(_ timer: Timer) {
        if lbl.backgroundColor == NSColor.white{
            lbl.backgroundColor = NSColor.black
        } else {
            lbl.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
        }
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: NSTextField!
}
```

Full project here: https://github.com/kindlychung/Flickalz

It's a simple app that changes the background color of a label at 80Hz. I would like to make that frequency customizable (through a text field or a slider) at run time but don't know how that may be done. Any ideas?

Comment: How the user can customize the frequency ? (button, textfield)

Comment: A textfield or slider. Edited.

Comment: The UI part is easy, I just can't figure out how to let the UI change the schedule at run time.

Comment: Inside your first viewController, you can put a slider that allows the user to change the frequency, than add an action (valueChanged) that will change the frequency of the textfield

Comment: Could you post your code in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to invalidate the timer and reschecule:

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    @IBOutlet weak var freqFld: NSTextField!

    @IBAction func setFreq(_ sender: NSButton) {
        restartTimer(freqFld.integerValue)
    }


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        window.backgroundColor = NSColor.black
    }

    var timer: Timer = Timer()

    func restartTimer(_ hz: Int) {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0/Double(hz * 2), repeats: true, block: toggleBackground)
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        restartTimer(40)
    }

    func toggleBackground(_ timer: Timer) {
        if window.backgroundColor == NSColor.white{
            window.backgroundColor = NSColor.black
        } else {
            window.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
        }
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }


}
```

The full project can be found here: https://github.com/kindlychung/Flickalz

Answer (score 0):

you can try to put a `UISlider` into your first `UIViewController`.

Then, follow this tutorial: http://sourcefreeze.com/ios-slider-uislider-example-using-swift/